# How can I resolve multi-arch conflict (liborc-0.4-dev)?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, gstreamer, multiarch

When trying to install the package `liborc-0.4-dev` together with `liborc-0.4-dev:arm64` on Ubuntu 18.04, I get a conflict:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liborc-0.4-dev : Conflicts: liborc-0.4-dev:arm64 but 1:0.4.28-1 is to be installed
 liborc-0.4-dev:arm64 : Conflicts: liborc-0.4-dev but 1:0.4.28-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas on how to go about solving this?

Or should I expect multi-arch support to be incomplete in ubuntu and move on to a different distribution?

Comment: What can't you just use the normal (default) version of that package? You may have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I needed both packages because I was maintaining a docker image used both to build and run a project locally, as well as cross compiling it to an arm based computer. The project depends on gstreamer, which again depends on orc. I guess I'll need to split this into two deparate docker images for each arch.

Comment: Would have been great to know that there was incomplete multiarch support before,  instead of having to discover it when adding a new dependency.

Comment: This is a bug which I filed here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/orc/+bug/1996552